# Syntax for singleton object

Tags: c#, watin

I have the following code to ensure only a single instance of a browser for Watin.

```
public sealed class BrowserIE
{

    static readonly IE _Instance = new IE();

    static BrowserIE()
    {
    }

    BrowserIE()
    {
    }

    public static IE Instance
    {
        get { return _Instance; }
    }
}
```

but I can't figure out where to apply the settings inside this class. How/where can I apply the following setting to the code above so they take affect before

`Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;`

I know I can use the following inside a method which works but I can't get the syntax right in my example above where _Instance is static readonly.

```
Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
_Instance = new IE();
```

Comment: You can use property initialization: `static readonly IE _Instance = new IE{ MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false };`

Comment: Also look into using `Lazy<IE> _Instance = new Lazy<IE>(() => new IE() { MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false });` then access it with `_Instance.Value`, this one of the things `System.Lazy` excels at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make use of the static constructor?

```
public sealed class BrowserIE
{
    static readonly IE _Instance;

    static BrowserIE()
    {
        Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
        _Instance = new IE();
    }

    BrowserIE()
    {
    }

    public static IE Instance
    {
        get { return _Instance; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement a thread save singleton and you use .NET 4.0 you could use the `System.Lazy<T>` class

```
public sealed class BrowserIE
{
    private static readonly Lazy<BrowserIE> _singleInstance = new Lazy<BrowserIE>(() => new BrowserIE());

    private BrowserIE() { }

    public static BrowserIEInstance
    {
        get { return _singleInstance.Value; }
    }
}
```